# How to use bootstrap-vue <b-form-checkbox>

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How can i use b-form-checkbox inside v-for

this is my code

```
<div v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
<b-form-checkbox name="check-button" switch>
</b-form-checkbox>
</div>
```

how can i pass user id and checkbox value into a method when i switch checkbox. Each checkbox have different user id

Anyone can help me,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Check out example 2 at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-checkbox/

Checkboxes – selected values (in this case the user's id) will be elements of the `selected` array because it's the `v-model` for the checkbox group. If a user id isn't in the array, it's not selected.

```
<b-form-group label="Users:">
  <b-form-checkbox-group id="checkbox-group" v-model="selected" name="selectedUsers">
    <b-form-checkbox v-for="(user, index) in users" :value="user.id" switch></b-form-checkbox>
  </b-form-checkbox-group>
</b-form-group>
```

Your component JS – there are a million ways to find out if a user is selected, below is an example method to see if a specific user id exists in the `selected` array.

```
data(){
  return {
    selected: []
  }
},
methods: {
  userIsSelected(userid){
    return this.selected.includes(userid)
  }
}
```

If you want to know when selection changes, you can watch the `selected` array:

```
data(){
  return {
    selected: []
  }
},
watch: {
  selected: {
    deep: true,
    handler: function(newValue){
      console.log("Selected users changed", newValue)
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  userIsSelected(userid){
    return this.selected.includes(userid)
  }
}
```

The `deep` property may or may not be necessary, but if your array ever includes objects or nested arrays it would be important.

Answer (score 1):

in case someone's still looking this is what I ended up doing.

if checkbox is ticked the current user object in the loop will be added to the selected [] array and removed when unticked so you can what you want in the changeMethod.

```
<div>
 <b-form-checkbox
    v-for="(user, index) in users"
    :key="index"
    v-model="selected"
    :value="user"
    name="checkbox"
    @change="changeMethod">
 </b-form-checkbox>
</div>

data(){
  return {
    selected: []
    users: [{
      name: 'user 1'
      id: '1'
     },...]
  }
},

methods: {
//handle what happens to your selected value when checkbox status changes
  changeMethod(){
    console.log(this.selected)
  }
}
```